# Is there a List Module Function that is like unzip with a Transformer

Tags: f#, standard-library

Is the below something I would find in the standard library?

```
split transformer1 ([], []) [("Foo", 1); ("Bar", 2); ("FooBar", 3)];;
> val it : string list * int list = (["FooBar"; "Bar"; "Foo"], [3; 2; 1])
```

here is my implementation

```
let split transformer defval stream =
    let rec split' s acc =
        match s with
            | [] -> acc
            | x::xs -> split' xs (transformer x acc)
    split' stream defval

let transformer1 (key, item) (akey, aitem) = (key::akey, item::aitem)
let transformer2 (key, item) (akey) = (key::akey)
let transformer3 (key, item) (a1, a2, a3) = (key::a1, item::a2, (item + 1)::a3)

split transformer1 ([], []) [("Foo", 1); ("Bar", 2); ("FooBar", 3)];;
split transformer2 ([]) [("Foo", 1); ("Bar", 2); ("FooBar", 3)];;
split transformer3 ([], [], []) [("Foo", 1); ("Bar", 2); ("FooBar", 3)];;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you've reinvented [List.fold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx). Here's how to reproduce your results with `fold`:

```
[("Foo", 1); ("Bar", 2); ("FooBar", 3)]
|> List.fold (fun (akey, aitem) (key, item) -> key::akey, item::aitem) ([], [])

[("Foo", 1); ("Bar", 2); ("FooBar", 3)]
|> List.fold (fun (akey) (key, item) -> key::akey) []

[("Foo", 1); ("Bar", 2); ("FooBar", 3)]
|> List.fold (fun (a1, a2, a3) (key, item) -> key::a1, item::a2, (item + 1)::a3) ([], [], [])
```

There's also a [Seq.fold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353471.aspx) function for (potentially lazily evaluated) sequences.

Comment: oh my - there is still a lot to learn for me in terms of FP. I must admit fold came into my mind but somehow the result of `fold` for me was always a scalar value. Returning a more complex structure has never crossed my mind. probably due to the fact that almost all examples for fold return a scalar.